# Weak entity having n instances as the 'one'

Tags: database-design, schema, erd

I'm struggling with a question, I'm just trying to figure is it even valid , if not where does it violates the rules of a weak entity relationship, I think it's not valid because how can a weak entity have n weak entities.

so is it valid ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can combine B and C to one new key that is used in A and also have a key from B directly, it is no problem as you have **two keys**.

If you don't add something new to the key you would have the **same** key, but referring to different entities A and C.

Ok as long as you don't try to 3NF or higher, it is at least possible but redundant.

> so C being weak can take n instances of A which is also weak and attached to the same owner?

Your relationship T is wrong. A weak relationship is always 1 to n or 1 to 1, never n:m. The essential part is that the weak entity has to know which key it relates to, see [http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/slides/slides2.pdf](http://infolab.stanford.edu/%7Eullman/fcdb/slides/slides2.pdf), so if it where a 1:n , it is possible.